# "Iceberg query cannot be parsed" when trying to create Iceberg table with MAP column data type in Athena?

Tags: amazon-athena, apache-iceberg

According to the [Athena Iceberg documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-iceberg-supported-data-types.html), the `map` type is supported.

Why do neither of these statements work?

```
CREATE TABLE iceberg_test1 (id string, themap map)
  LOCATION 's3://mybucket/test/iceberg1'
  TBLPROPERTIES ( 'table_type' = 'ICEBERG' );
```

Error:

> Iceberg query cannot be parsed

Second try:

```
CREATE TABLE iceberg_test1 (id string, themap map<varchar,varchar>)
  LOCATION 's3://mybucket/test/iceberg1'
  TBLPROPERTIES ( 'table_type' = 'ICEBERG' );
```

Same error:

> Iceberg query cannot be parsed

Answer (score 1):

Neither `map` (without specifying the key/value types) nor `varchar` are valid Iceberg types. See the Iceberg documentation for [valid types](https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/schemas).

```
CREATE TABLE iceberg_test1 (id string, themap map<string, string>)
  LOCATION 's3://mybucket/test/iceberg1'
  TBLPROPERTIES ( 'table_type' = 'ICEBERG' );
```

will work as long as you have permissions to access the S3 location.